# Is there any way to read a file on server without downloading in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, xlsx, file-read

I want to read multiple files,right now I am downloading to local and reading, but i wanted to know if there is any way to read or parse the .xlsx file by directly connecting to the server?

Comment: How to connect to the server in that case and find the file in it?@tyehia @twg

Comment: Well, you can stream a file into a parser as long as the parser accepts streamed input and thus it would be parsed as it was read a piece at a time rather than downloading the whole thing and then parsing.  Beyond that, it is not clear exactly what you're asking.  Any more specific advice would need to know exactly what you are using to parse the `.xlsx` file since that's where the functionality needs to be.

Comment: I am using Xlsx module to parse currently after downloading the file.. @jfriend00

Comment: Upon first inspection, I don't' see any ability to incrementally parse using that module.  It appears that `.read()` wants the entire data either in file or in memory.  You would need to find a different parser that could handle incremental parsing, ideally from a node.js stream.

Comment: We read the workbook ryt @jfriend00 like parsing the worksheets

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means.

Comment: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json  like this @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

try here..this should work for what you asked and a great deal more.

[xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

You should be able to read the file on the sever, parse through it, get the info you want without downloading to your hard drive.

Comment: And, how exactly would the OP use this module to incrementally read/parse without first reading the entire file into memory or hard disk?  Pointing the OP to a module with no explanation about how this would solve their problem is not a particularly useful answer here on stack overflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 apologies you are correct. His question was though was formulated "to read or parse the .xlsx file by directly connecting to the server?" which led me to believe all he required was a nudge towards the xlsx library and its functionality. He can avoid hard disk downloading and reading and, as all said above read it in streams. I will make sure my answers in the future are with as complete info as possible on the subject. I assumed the OP wanted information on where to look. Which obviously was a bad assumption.

Comment: So, if you know how the OP can parse the file without downloading the file first, why don't you edit your answer to actually show that?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer above question, i ended up using below approach as same situation encountered with me.

```
// Requiring modules
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

// Creating server to accept request
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    // Parsing the URL
    var request = url.parse(req.url, true);

    // Extracting the path of file
    var action = request.pathname;

    // Path Refinements
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname,
            action).split("%20").join(" ");

    // Checking if the path exists
    fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {

        if (!exists) {
            res.writeHead(404, {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            res.end("404 Not Found");
            return;
        }

        // Extracting file extension
        var ext = path.extname(action);

        // Setting default Content-Type
        var contentType = "text/plain";

        // Checking if the extention of
        // image is '.png'
        if (ext === ".png") {
            contentType = "image/png";
        }

        // Setting the headers
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": contentType });

        // Reading the file
        fs.readFile(filePath,
            function (err, content) {
                // Serving the image
                res.end(content);
            });
    });
})

// Listening to the PORT: 3000
.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```